# Subqueries are not allowed in this context

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to prevent further duplicates from being added to my table while allowing existing duplicates to remain. I thought I could accomplish this using a filtered index as follows.

But when I execute the following query:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_Account
ON Holdings(Account)
WHERE Account NOT IN (select Account from Holdings)
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 1046, Level 15, State 1, Line 57
> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

How can I prevent further duplicates from being added?

Comment: So, you are trying to create an index on a table where the column is not in the table?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: The column is in the table and it already got duplicates, I'm trying to avoid future duplicates without deleting duplicate records.

Comment: @KatisoKoqo an index is created on the existing data... so if you already have duplicates, even if that syntax was allowed, it would fail. There is no setting to ignore existing duplicates. [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43823/can-i-add-a-unique-constraint-that-ignores-existing-violations) might be the solution you are looking for.

Comment: But if I try something like where Account not in (1, 2, 3) it works fine. I want a way to ignore existing data.

Comment: But you cannot filter the index just for "future" data without hardcoding that list of IDs in the constraint definition. Perhaps a filtered indexed view? Which I struggle to figure out a way to define - so maybe not.

Comment: I want to filter on a list of IDs that are already there without having to remove duplicates and nulls.

Comment: @DaleK, that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve, I've looked into the link you provided and I've been there before.

Comment: @KatisoKoqo so what about that answer doesn't work for you?

Comment: @DaleK, that answer doesn't work for me as it won't prevent duplicates on multiple rows.

Comment: @KatisoKoqo a trigger is your only option then.

Comment: You can't use `subquery in unique filtered index` like this code. absolutely this code is not work and this because you choose not valid object for this aim. you should be use trigger

Answer (score 2):

You can't have your cake and eat it.

Either

1. decide that your data should have integrity and purge the duplicated before adding the unique index (filtering it for the reason you mention does not make sense)
   or
2. enforce your logic with an insert trigger:

```
    create trigger no_more_duplicates on Holdings
    after insert as
        if exists
        (
            select 1 
            from inserted 
            where inserted.Account IN (select Account from Holdings) 
        )
            raiserror('Cannot add duplicates',16,0)
    end -- trigger
```

This trigger's a bit dumb, it will not prevent duplicates on a multiple-row insert, nor will it let the nonduplicate ones be saved. Yet, it's enough that you get the picture.

Comment: @Dale K Thanks for the edit, what was I doing wrong? Code Sample seemed not to be working

Comment: You might want to add a check to see if duplicates are in the inserted table too. IF EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM Inserted GROUP BY Account HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

Answer (score 1):

`raiserror` in a trigger will not automatically rollback the transaction, but `throw` will.  Alternatively you can `raiserror` and `rollback`.

Also with an AFTER trigger the data in the INSERTED virtual table is already present in the table.  So a trigger would need to look like:

```
use tempdb
drop table if exists Holdings 
create table Holdings(id int primary key, Account int)

go
    create or alter trigger no_more_duplicates on Holdings
    after insert as
    begin
        if exists
        (
            select 1 
            from inserted 
            where inserted.Account IN (select Account from Holdings where id <> inserted.id) 
        )
        begin
           throw 60000, 'Cannot add duplicates', 1 ;
          --raiserror('Cannot add duplicates',16,1)
        end;
    end -- trigger
go
insert into Holdings(id,Account) values (1,1)
go
insert into Holdings(id,Account) values (2,1)
go
select * from holdings
```